# writeLines to an outside file in a loop

Tags: r, loops

I'm fairly new to R, but basically I want to write certain parts of a data frame as text to an outside txt file. This is the code that I have,

```
for (i in 1:nrow(myd)) {
    if (i > nrow(myd)) {
      fileConn<-file("output.txt")
      writeLines(c(paste0(myd[i,2]),paste0(myd[i,4]), paste0(myd[i,11]),paste0(myd[i,8])), fileConn)
  } else
    close(fileConn)
}
```

This code only gives me the last row's data, is there a way to append each loop?

Comment: The condition `i > nrow(myd)` is never `TRUE`. Do you want the elements of vector `c(...)` in separate lines? Anyway, try `?cat`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with `cat`. Write the columns and then call `cat` once again to write a newline character.
The condition in the loop will write the wanted columns of all even numbered rows.
Tested with a mock data set, since there is none in the question.

```r
myd <- sapply(1:11, \(x) rep(sprintf("column %d", x), 5))
myd <- as.data.frame(myd)
myd[[2]] <- letters[1:5]

output <- "output.txt"
fileConn <- file(output, open = "wt")
for (i in 1:nrow(myd)) {
  if(i %% 2 == 0) {
    cat(myd[i,2],  myd[i,4], myd[i,11], myd[i,8],
        file = fileConn, append = TRUE)
    cat("\n", file = fileConn, append = TRUE)
  }
}
close(fileConn)
readLines(output)
#> [1] "b column 4 column 11 column 8" "d column 4 column 11 column 8"

unlink(output)  # final clean-up
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I also found this to be satisfactory for my purposes:

```
  for (i in 1:nrow(myd)) {
  cat(paste0(myd[i,c(2,4,11,8)]), file = "my_file.txt", sep = "\n", append = TRUE)
  }
```

Anyone knows how I can add a line of text (tag) before every columns text?
Such as:

**Type** JOUR

**Title** A game for process mapping in office and knowledge work

**Year** 2021

**Abstract** The number of publications on ...